# QA Issue: libvncserver: Files/directories were installed but not shipped in any package:

Tags: yocto, openembedded

While generating sato image by `bitbake core-iamge-sato`, I am getting following errors

```
ERROR: libvncserver-0.9.12+gitAUTOINC+c0a23857a5-r0 do_package: QA Issue: libvncserver: Files/directories were installed but not shipped in any package:
  /usr/lib/libvncclient.so
  /usr/lib/libvncserver.so
  /usr/lib/libvncserver.so.1
  /usr/lib/libvncclient.so.0.9.12
  /usr/lib/libvncclient.so.1
  /usr/lib/libvncserver.so.0.9.12
  /usr/lib/pkgconfig
  /usr/lib/pkgconfig/libvncclient.pc
  /usr/lib/pkgconfig/libvncserver.pc
Please set FILES such that these items are packaged. Alternatively if they are unneeded, avoid installing them or delete them within do_install.
libvncserver: 9 installed and not shipped files. [installed-vs-shipped]
ERROR: libvncserver-0.9.12+gitAUTOINC+c0a23857a5-r0 do_package: Fatal QA errors found, failing task.
ERROR: libvncserver-0.9.12+gitAUTOINC+c0a23857a5-r0 do_package: 
ERROR: libvncserver-0.9.12+gitAUTOINC+c0a23857a5-r0 do_package: Function failed: do_package
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/panther2/warrior/build/tmp/work/corei7-64-poky-linux/libvncserver/0.9.12+gitAUTOINC+c0a23857a5-r0/temp/log.do_package.101719
ERROR: Task (/home/panther2/warrior/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-oe/recipes-graphics/libvncserver/libvncserver_git.bb:do_package) failed with exit code '1'
```

I am building for `warrior` branch. As a solution I tried adding following lines in `libvncserver_git.bb` but nothing worked out. Can anyone help?

```
FILES_${PN} += " \
    ${libdir}/libvncclient.so \
    ${libdir}/libvncserver.so \
    ${libdir}/libvncserver.so.1 \
    ${libdir}/libvncclient.so.0.9.12 \
    ${libdir}/libvncclient.so.1 \
    ${libdir}/libvncserver.so.0.9.12 \
    ${libdir}/pkgconfig \ 
    ${libdir}/pkgconfig/libvncclient.pc \
    ${libdir}/pkgconfig/libvncserver.pc \
"
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the issue but it seems to have been worked around in master with a version upgrade http://lists.openembedded.org/pipermail/openembedded-devel/2019-July/200552.html

Comment: It worked out for me, Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 1):

Background: you're using a configuration where `$libdir` isn't `/usr/lib` (multilib, probably) but the upstream doesn't care and installs to `/usr/lib` anyway, which is a bug upstream.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in comment, I have resolved the error by replacing recipe file from master branch(`libvncserver_0.9.12.bb`). I was using `warrior` branch recipe `libvncserver_git.bb` which causes error.