# Confusion regarding BitBake error "Files/directories were installed but not shipped in any package"

Tags: gcc, installation, yocto, bitbake, yocto-recipe

I am new to Yocto and the BitBake "eco system".

In order to try and search for a solution to my probelm I went over the following, YET, as of my understanding, the symptom is similar (or identical) BUT the situation there is different:

[First similar scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49748528/yocto-files-directories-were-installed-but-not-shipped-in-any-package)

[second similar scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57951878/qa-issue-libvncserver-files-directories-were-installed-but-not-shipped-in-any)

What I wish to achive is to create an image *without* the header files of `gcc` under `/usr/lib64/${TARGET_SYS}/${BINV}/include`. In order to do that, what I did is "overriding" the `do_install_append()` method of the `gcc_9.2.bb` recipe by "adding" to it the removal of the irrelevant files by performing: `rm -rf ${D}${gcclibdir}/${TARGET_SYS}/${BINV}/include` and `rm -rf ${D}${gcclibdir}/${TARGET_SYS}/${BINV}/include-fixed` at the very end of this function (thus removing all files from the include and include-fixed folders).

This works fine for me (when I load the resulting image I do not see header files of `gcc` I used to see before). ***Neverthelss***, what I **still** see (have) on the image are files related to the `gcc-sanitizers_9.2.bb` recipe which are under the folder (in the final image): `/usr/lib64/${TARGET_SYS}/${BINV}/include/sanitizer`:

Which are:
`asan_interface.h  common_interface_defs.h  lsan_interface.h  tsan_interface.h`

What I did to remove these files (all 4 of them) is removing them in the `do_install_append()` of my "derived" `gcc-sanitzers_9.2.bbappend` recipe, like so:

```
do_install_append () {
    rm -rf ${D}${libdir}/gcc/${TARGET_SYS}/${BINV}/include/sanitizer/
}
```

Now in this case, i.e. - there are both my derived `gcc_9.2.bbappend` and `gcc-sanitzers_9.2.bbappend` with the respective functions implementation (as described above), I get the following error:

> ERROR: gcc-sanitizers-9.2.0-r0 do_package: QA Issue: gcc-sanitizers: Files/directories were installed but not shipped in any package:
> /usr/lib64/gcc/include

> Please set FILES such that these items are packaged. Alternatively if they are unneeded, avoid installing them or delete them within do_install.
> gcc-sanitizers: 4 installed and not shipped files. [installed-vs-shipped]

What I'm confused about is that if an error is to raise, I would expect an error "the other way around", meaning something like:"Files/directories are NOT installed but are about to be shipped in the package..." (again, this is an hypothetic error message of mine).

What am I missing here? How can I achive my goal of not having the header files (and only them) in my final image?